# Tag <uses-permission> missing required attribute name

Tags: java, android, xml

I am getting this error I change everything almost setwallpaper to set wallpapermanager and trget sdk and min is also set. Still not find the solution how to remove manifest error.
Permission added already for set_Wallpaper.

- [2015-01-17 07:51:51 -
  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper]
  Parser exception for
  C:\Workspaces\MakingFun\AndroidMe\AndroidManifest.xml: The element
  type "uses-permission" must be terminated by the matching end-tag
  "". [2015-01-17 07:51:51 - AndroidMe] Error in an
  XML file: aborting build.

========================================================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
    <uses-permission />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidme.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidme.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidme.MainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidme.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidme.Menu" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

           <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidme.TextPlay"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidme.Email"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidme.Camera"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code :

```
      @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bsetwalpapr:

            try {
                WallpaperManager Setwalpaper = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
                Setwalpaper.setBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.ibtakenimage:
            i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you defined `<uses-permission />` but what uses permission? Sure thing you need to add name there or remove this useless tag at all.

Check the line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission />
```

Comment: Is the set wallpaper permission a dangerous one? Meaning, I need to ask the user to access the permission?

Comment: @AviParshan, you don't need [it is normal](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_WALLPAPER)